# Why does Dart JIT code perform better than Dart exe code for these programs?

Tags: dart

[regex-redux #2](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/regexredux-dartexe-2.html)
exe 20.05 secs
jit 6.70 secs

[regex-redux #3](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/regexredux-dartjit-3.html)
exe 12.09 secs
jit 5.11 secs

[regex-redux #4](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/regexredux-dartexe-4.html)
exe 17.76 secs
jit 5.53 secs

[regex-redux #5](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/regexredux-dartjit-5.html)
exe 12.18 secs
jit 4.11 secs

And what do I need to change to make `compile exe` produce that faster code?

[`dart compile exe` programs.](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/measurements/dartexe.html)

[`dart run` programs.](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/measurements/dartjit.html)

Comment: It is know that `RegExp` performance is worse when compiled versus JIT: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39260 . The situation should have been much improved lately but still not perfect. I will suggest you post your tests to the GitHub issue so the developers have some new test cases and can maybe give you some advice until the Dart compiler gets better in understanding RegExp.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37774.